# How to provide completion of interactive function from a request?

Tags: emacs, completion

I would like to provide completion for an emacs interactive function whose content would be based on a HTTP request's content.
Here, the `TODO` explains it all.

```
(defun sensei-record-flow (flow-type)
  "Interactive function to record change in flow."
  
  (interactive (list (completing-read
                      "Flow: "
                      ;; TODO need to get the completion from a variable filled with user's
                      ;; flow types
                      '(("Foo" Foo) ("Bar" Bar) ("Baz" Baz))
                      nil t)))
  (let ((directory (projectile-project-root)))
    (setq sensei-cur-directory directory)
    (sensei-send-event-flow directory flow-type))
  )
```

How can I do that? `request.el` provides a `:completion` key to block until completion of a request, but it's not clear to me how to do that? I think what I need is to make the `interactive` function a continuation of the call to `senseiilist-flows` but I don't know how to do that in elisp.

EDIT: Here is the code of `sensei-list-flows` based on `request.el`

```
(defun sensei-list-flows (on-success)
  "List available flow types for the current user.

ON-SUCCESS is a function that's called upon successful completion of the call
and is passed a list of symbols listing user-defined flow names."
  (let* ((config (sensei-read-config))
         (auth-token (cdr (assoc 'authToken config)))
         (username (cdr (assoc 'configUser config)))
         (server-uri (cdr (assoc 'serverUri config))))
    (request (concat server-uri "api/users/" username)
      :headers `(("Content-Type" . "application/json")
                 ("X-API-Version" . "0.38.0")
                 ("Authorization" . ,(concat "Bearer " auth-token)))
      :parser 'json-read
      :error  (cl-function (lambda (&rest args &key error-thrown &allow-other-keys)
                             (message "Got error: %S" error-thrown)))
      :success  (cl-function (lambda (&key data &allow-other-keys)
                               (funcall on-success
                                     (map 'list 'car (cdr (assoc 'userFlowTypes data)))))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about `request.el` and you haven't included any call to a `list-flows` in your quoted code and so that's impossible to comment on; but OOTB you would use <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `url-retrieve-synchronously` to fetch something via http like that.

In the resulting buffer, the `url-http-end-of-headers` variable is of particular note (+1 to get to the start of the content); and you may wish to check the `url-http-*` vars in that buffer in general.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason I have not included `list-flows` function is because it's "just" a copy-paste of `request.el`'s documentation, I will add a link to the page. The reason I am using request.el is that it popped up while searching for a way to request stuff in emacs but it seems url-retrieve-synchronously is what I am looking for.

Comment: But actually, my main problem is to understand how to produce a completion list within `interactive` block out of such a synchronous call. I will go through interactive's help again.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve what I want using `url-insert-file-contents` which is similar to `url-retrieve-synchronously`:

```
(defun sensei-list-flows ()
  "List available flow types for the current user."
  (let* ((config (sensei-read-config))
         (auth-token (cdr (assoc 'authToken config)))
         (username (cdr (assoc 'configUser config)))
         (server-uri (cdr (assoc 'serverUri config)))
         (url-request-extra-headers `(("Content-Type" . "application/json")
                 ("X-API-Version" . "0.38.0")
                 ("Authorization" . ,(concat "Bearer " auth-token)))))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (url-insert-file-contents (concat server-uri "api/users/" username))
      (let ((flows (cdr (assoc 'userFlowTypes (json-parse-buffer :object-type 'alist)))))
        (map 'list 'car flows)))))
```

Then interactive completion is trivial:

```
(defun sensei-record-flow (flow-type)
  "Interactive function to record change in flow."

  (interactive (list (completing-read
                      "Flow: "
                      (sensei-list-flows)
                      nil t)))
  (let ((directory (projectile-project-root)))
    (setq sensei-cur-directory directory)
    (sensei-send-event-flow directory flow-type))
  )
```